# How to bold a part of the text?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

What should I add if I would like to bold just these particular text
"Tutor Description: ",
"Tutor Email:  ",
"Phone Number: ",
"Date Register: ",
"Subject List: ".

```
               Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                 Text("Tutor Description: \n"
                  +tutorList[index].tutorDescription.toString(),),

                 Text("Tutor Email:  " +
                    tutorList[index].tutorEmail.toString()),

                 Text("Phone Number " +
                     tutorList[index].tutorPhone.toString()),

                 Text("Date Register: " + df.format(DateTime.parse(
                         tutorList[index].tutorDatereg.toString()))),

                 Text("Subject List: " +tutorList[index].subjectsName.toString()),
               ]),
```

Comment: Did you try this?  ```style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use RichText instead of simple Text widget if you want to make some part bold of text.

For Example -

Expected Result = "This is **bold** string";

```
 RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          children: [
            TextSpan(text: "This is "),
            TextSpan(text: "Bold ", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            TextSpan(text: "string"),
          ]
        ),
    );
```

For more details - [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)